# Listing a directory, Nginx without 403 error

Tags: nginx

I have an Nginx server on my rasbperry pi and I want to list a directory from my extern disk.

So, in `/var/www`, I have a symbolic link who point to my disk `/var/www/data -> /media/HDD`

My disk has www-data as owner, so, there is no problem of permission but, It's not working!
If I place a "index.html" in the directory, it's ok, I can see the page but, without, Nginx don't list the directory.

In `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`,
I have :

```
server {    
    location /data {
            autoindex on;
    }    
}
```

And I've tried

```
location /var/www/data {
        autoindex on;
}
```

It's the same...

Have you got the solution to fix my problem ?

Thank you ;)

Comment: is `/media/HDD` executable?

Comment: Yes, chmod 777 for HDD....

Comment: try move your `autoindex on;` code outside the `location` block

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you need to put `try_files`

```
server {
  root /var/www;
  location /data {
    autoindex on;
    try_files $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```